# How to read rows and headers separately into a dataset?

Tags: import, dataset

Suppose that the information for constructing a dataset is split over two separate files: one file contains the numeric data, and a second file contains the names of the columns.

Is there a simple way to create a dataset from these two separate files?

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DatasetWithHeaders

Answer (score 6):

```
columnames=CharacterRange["a","h"];
data= RandomInteger[9,{20,8}];

ds=Dataset[AssociationThread[columnames->#]&/@data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a second way.  Like kglr's solution, this one also uses `AssociationThread`, but applies it only once:

```
makeDataset[columns_, columnLabels_] := Module[{labeledColumns, records},
   labeledColumns = AssociationThread[columnLabels, columns];
   records = Transpose[labeledColumns, AllowedHeads -> All];
   Dataset[records]
];
```

The importer can be easily written in terms of `makeDataset`:

```
readDataset[datafile_, headerfile_] := Module[{columns, columnLabels},
   columns = Transpose[Import[datafile]];
   columnLabels = First[Import[headerfile]];
   makeDataset[columns, columnLabels]
];
```